# R - what is magnitude of region of similarity (epsilon) when using tost() from equivalence package

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, equivalence, tost

I have two vectors:

```
library(equivalence)
a <- c(32, 18, 23,  4,  9, 19, 34, 22, 24, 26,  8, 10, 18)
b <- c(28, 32, 20, 10,  7, 31, 18, 25, 22, 28, 10,  9, 21)
tost(a, b, epsilon=5)
```

Now when I use `tost()` (from following library: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/equivalence/equivalence.pdf), what exactly does the `epsilon=5` mean? Does it mean one of them can have mean $5\%$ higher of lower, or is it not $\%$ and is just $\pm5$?

I can't find anything concrete on that. Does it have another name?

Comment: What package is that function from? How can we determine how it works if you don't even tell us what it is?

Comment: Added additional information. It's from package equivalence (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/equivalence/equivalence.pdf)

Comment: The other functions in that package seem to use standard deviation units for the margin. You can always look at the source code for a definitive answer of course. R is open source.

Comment: @mdewey that's true. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a synonym to the equivalence margin. Because there is no exact equivalence it is a range of the similarity.

Here is a article which describes the [Equivalence and Noninferiority Testing](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3019319/).

EDIT: For the hypothesis testing it is necessary to set a acceptable range of unequality. The deviation of the equal margin can be in positive and negative direction. So the 5 means it is 5% higher or lower. I am not sure about the edit, it would be nice if somebody verify this...

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more details here rather than just a link?

Answer (score 1):

I was also wondering if an epsilon of 2 sets a margin of 2 above and 2 below or a margin of 1  above and 1 below for a total rang of 2. As I couldn't find the answer nor understand the R code I contacted directly the author of the package "equivalence", professor Robinson, who very kindly answered:

> An epsilon of 2 sets margin for 2 above and 2 below.